# Cómo subir una foto con CodeIgnither + Ajax?

Tags: jquery, ajax, codeigniter, fileupload

Quiero subir una foto de un formulario y que la página no se refresque ni tenga que darle a subir, solo quiero hacerlo cuando se establezca una imagen en el input.

No veo el error, he comprobado y no sube foto ni a la carpeta ni actualiza el campo de la tabla en la BD.

¿Donde tengo estoy cometiendo el error? Gracias de antemano.

Muestro a continuación lo que tengo:

**HTML**

```
    <form name="photo" id="imageUploadForm" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="/gestion/index.php/erp/usuarios" method="post">
     <input type="hidden" name="tabla" value="clientes">
     <input type="hidden" name="campo" value="FOTO">
     <input type="hidden" name="id" value="2">
     <input type="file" id="ImageBrowse" name="foto" style="" onchange="$('#imageUploadForm').submit();">
    </form>
```

**Ajax**

```
$(document).ready(function (e) {
        $('#imageUploadForm').on('submit',(function(e) {
            console.log("Submit.");
            e.preventDefault();
            var formData = new FormData(this);

           $.ajax({
                type:'POST',
                url: $(this).attr('action'),
                data:formData,
                cache:false,
                contentType: false,
                processData: false,
                success:function(data){
                    console.log("success");
                    console.log(data);
                },
                error: function(data){
                    console.log("error");
                    console.log(data);
                }
            });
        }));
    });
```

**En el controlador:**

```
public function sube_foto() {

        $tabla = $this->input->post('tabla');
        $campo = $this->input->post('campo');
        $id = $this->input->post('id');

        $new_name = $this->session->userdata('iduser') . "_".$tabla."_" . date('Ymdhis');

        $config['file_name'] = $new_name;
        $config['upload_path'] = './img/'.$tabla;
        $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png|jpeg';
        $config['max_size'] = 1000;
        $config['max_width'] = 2048;
        $config['max_height'] = 2048;

        $this->upload->initialize($config);
        $this->load->library('upload', $config);

        if (!$this->upload->do_upload('foto')) {
            $data['aviso'] = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors());
        } else {

            $subida = $this->upload->data();
            $foto = $new_name . $subida['file_ext'];
            //La siguiente llamada funciona correctamente, la uso para otras funciones.
            $this->Consultas_m->update_tabla($tabla, $campo, $foto, $id);
        }
    }
```

Comment: ¿Has tratado de hacer un debug del FormData? Es decir, ¿si te muestra un objeto que puedas subir?

Comment: no veo nada mal en el flujo entre ajax y tu función php mete un try-catch en la función php y devuelve la excepción a ver si logras algo

Comment: Es que yo pienso que no llega a la función PHP.

Comment: Hola buenos dias, quizas el problema esta en el action del formulario, podrias intentar cambiando 

action="/gestion/index.php/erp/usuarios"
por
action="<?php echo base_url('index.php/gestion/index.php/erp/usuarios);?>"

ademas seria bueno ver el resultado obtenido en las herramientas de desarrollador del navegador.

Saludos.